# Use the method of variation of parameters : $y'' + 2y' − 3y = 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use the method of variation of parameters to find a general solution to

$$y'' + 2y' − 3y = 1$$

**My Work**

$$2dy/dx =3y+1$$

$$(2/3)(3dy/(3y+1)=dx$$

$$(2/3)ln(3y+1)=x $$

stuck here

Comment: Notice that $y\equiv-1/3$ is a solution.

Answer (score 3):

$$y''+2y'-3y=0$$ is the homogeneous equation. therefore auxiliary equation is $$m^2+2m-3=0$$
Solving, $$m=-3,1$$ Hence complementary function $$y_c=c_1e^{-3x}+c_2e^x$$ 
Let the particular integral be $$y_p=v_1(x)y_1(x)+v_2(x)y_2(x)$$ where $y_1(x)=e^{-3x}$ and $y_2(x)=e^x$. Now apply variation of parameters to find $v_1$ and $v_2$. General solution is $y=y_c+y_p$

Comment: how i'm also stuck here ??

Comment: http://www.math.utah.edu/~gustafso/2250variation-of-parameters.pdf See here

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**

1) You have not considered the second derivative $y''$!

2) First solve the homogeneous equation $y'' + 2y' − 3y = 0$

3) Find a particular solution to $y'' + 2y' − 3y = 1$. In this step you can use the method of variation of parameters.

4) Sum what you obtained from $(2)$ and $(3)$. This will be the general solution.

Comment: Well, for 3), I would suggest a constant $y$... :-)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: Yeah, I know that but I said the OP **can** use that as he is insisting to use the method! Of course guessing is easier here! :)

Comment: You are right, I didn't pay attention that he insists to use this method. Bad exercise, it's too easy to solve "directly".

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: I don't know where are these down-voters! :D It seems somebody down-voted my answer! :/

Comment: What really annoys me is that the OP is completely ignoring what the question asks. This and the other problems they posted.